# Problems with the command which makes you know if the hard disk is hdd or ssd

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, ssd, disk, 20.10

I want to have a script which tells me what sort of disk I have on my laptop.

I have found a command used how to know if my disk is a ssd or hdd i.e. :

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
```

unfortunately I get:

```
cat: /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational: No such file or directory
```

my ubuntu version is 20.10.

EDIT: the command:

`lsblk | grep disk`

gives

`nvme0n1     259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk`

Is there another command related to my issue?

Comment: you could now also remove your comment ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output of `lsblk` shows that your device is called `nvme0n1` instead of `sda`.

Try:

```
cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/rotational
```

- 0 = **not** rotational = SSD
- 1 = rotational = HDD

Comment: no, please see my update.